# Why not allowing subclasses to override methods can lead to creation of immutable objects?

Tags: java, overriding, subclass, immutability, final

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of defining immutable objects. I have read in Java tutorial oracle that one of the ways to create immutable objects is

> Don't allow subclasses to override methods. The simplest way to do this is to declare the class as final.

My question is, why not allowing subclasses to override methods can leads to creation of immutable objects? I'm struggling to understand the connection here.

Comment: I think the right question would be "Why allowing subclasses to override methods is a necessary step in designing an immutable object"? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose String's methods could be extended by another class.  There's no guarantee that the other class would be immutable like String is.

So if you call some library method and get a String back, will that String change or not?  Is it the String base class or something that extended it that is mutable?  String is a final class, so we don't have to worry about that.

I made an example of the confusion below:

```
public class WhyImmutableClassesShouldBeFinal {
    /*
     * This is an immutable class
     */
    private static class ImmutableClass {
        private final String data;

        public ImmutableClass(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    /*
     * This extends an immutable class, but is not immutable.
     */
    private static class NotSoImmutableClass extends ImmutableClass {
        private int oops;

        public NotSoImmutableClass() {
            super("WHATEVER");
        }

        public String getData() {
            return Integer.toString(oops++);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Here's some function that looks like it returns an immutable class but
     * doesn't.
     */
    private static ImmutableClass immutableClassProducer() {
        return new NotSoImmutableClass();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * I called a method and got an ImmutableClass back.
         */
        ImmutableClass c = immutableClassProducer();

        /*
         * But why is the value changing?
         */
        System.out.println(c.getData());
        System.out.println(c.getData());
        System.out.println(c.getData());
        System.out.println(c.getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it to me and for the example!! Really appreicate your help!!